# IsLockedOut is false when LockoutEnd is future date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to enable lockouts when users fail authentication more than 5 times. I have added the necessary code to enable lockout options:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    // This is set to 365 but the user will get enabled again on password reset.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
})
```

I have also set `lockoutOnFailure` to true in the `PasswordSignInAsync` method as shown below:

[image: IsLockedOut is false]

When I check `AspNetUsers` table in the database it does show `LockoutEnabled` as true and the `LockoutEnd` is :

> 2022-02-23 15:29:53.454012+00

Am I missing something somewhere?

EDIT

Adding some more information that may be relevant. I ran an update script on the `AspNetUsers` table to set `LockoutEnabled` to true for all existing non admin users. Since I have `AllowedForNewUsers` set to true for all new users, I added some logic to manually set the `LockoutEnabled` flag to false for new admins. To do this, I added this `LockoutEnabled` bool property to `ApplicationUser` model. It seems this does pick up the value from the database but when I step through on debug it doesn't seem to link up with ASP Net Identity:

[image: IdentityUser LockoutEnabled is false]

Comment: Have you followed the example from the docs, including IdentityOptions config? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lockout

Comment: @ChrisPickford I did follow these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to add `LockoutEnabled` to the `ApplicationUser` model.